# How to customize score calculate in ElasticSearch?

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch

I have the following request.

```
    {'bool':
         {'must': [
              {"terms": {"state.keyword": ["Alaska", "Alabama"]}
          ],
          'should': [
              {'match': {'abstract': 'Spill and Overfill Prevention 18 AAC 78.045'}},
              {'match': {'title': 'Spill and Overfill Prevention 18 AAC 78.045'}},
              {'constant_score': {
                  'filter': {
                      'match': {'title': 'Spill and Overfill Prevention 18 AAC 78.045'}
                  }
              }}
          ]}
     }
```

*Need to calculate the score by `title` (match).*

For this I tried using `constant_score`.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-constant-score-query.html

However, it did not give the expected effect. It just increments the result of each element by exactly 1.

Here is the result of analyze

```
{'took': 21, 'timed_out': False, '_shards': {'total': 1, 'successful': 1, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0}, 'hits': {'total': {'value': 6, 'relation': 'eq'}, 'max_score'
: 4.754379, 'hits': [{'_index': 'articles', '_type': '_doc', '_id': '483703', '_score': 4.754379, '_source':
```

Here is the explain result

```
{'_index': 'articles', '_type': '_doc', '_id': '483703', 'matched': True, 'explanation': {'value': 6.6602507, 'description': 'sum of:', 'details': [{'value': 0.150
05009, 'description': 'weight(legal_language:and in 2) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:', 'details': [{'value': 0.15005009, 'description': 'score(freq=14.0), compu
ted as boost * idf * tf from:', 'details': [{'value': 2.2, 'description': 'boost', 'details': []}, {'value': 0.074107975, 'description': 'idf, computed as log(1 +
(N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:', 'details': [{'value': 6, 'description': 'n, number of documents containing term', 'details': []}, {'value': 6, 'description': 'N
, total number of documents with field', 'details': []}]}, {'value': 0.92034066, 'description': 'tf, computed as freq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl / avgdl)) from
:', 'details': [{'value': 14.0, 'description': 'freq, occurrences of term within document', 'details': []}, {'value': 1.2, 'description': 'k1, term saturation para
meter', 'details': []}, {'value': 0.75, 'description': 'b, length normalization parameter', 'details': []}, {'value': 504.0, 'description': 'dl, length of field (a
pproximate)', 'details': []}, {'value': 497.5, 'description': 'avgdl, average length of field', 'details': []}]}]}]}, {'value': 0.3779109, 'description': 'weight(l
egal_language:18 in 2) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:', 'details': [{'value': 0.3779109, 'description': 'score(freq=3.0), computed as boost * idf * tf from:', 'd
etails': [{'value': 2.2, 'description': 'boost', 'details': []}, {'value': 0.24116206, 'description': 'idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:',
'details': [{'value': 5, 'description': 'n, number of documents containing term', 'details': []}, {'value': 6, 'description': 'N, total number of documents with fi
eld', 'details': []}]}, {'value': 0.7122915, 'description': 'tf, computed as freq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl / avgdl)) from:', 'details': [{'value': 3.0, 'desc
ription': 'freq, occurrences of term within document', 'details': []}, {'value': 1.2, 'description': 'k1, term saturation parameter', 'details': []}, {'value': 0.7
5, 'description': 'b, length normalization parameter', 'details': []}, {'value': 504.0, 'description': 'dl, length of field (approximate)', 'details': []}, {'value
': 497.5, 'description': 'avgdl, average length of field', 'details': []}]}]}]}, {'value': 0.3779109, 'description': 'weight(legal_language:aac in 2) [PerFieldSimi
larity], result of:', 'details': [{'value': 0.3779109, 'description': 'score(freq=3.0), computed as boost * idf * tf from:', 'details': [{'value': 2.2, 'descriptio
n': 'boost', 'details': []}, {'value': 0.24116206, 'description': 'idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:', 'details': [{'value': 5, 'descriptio
n': 'n, number of documents containing term', 'details': []}, {'value': 6, 'description': 'N, total number of documents with field', 'details': []}]}, {'value': 0.
7122915, 'description': 'tf, computed as freq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl / avgdl)) from:', 'details': [{'value': 3.0, 'description': 'freq, occurrences of term
within document', 'details': []}, {'value': 1.2, 'description': 'k1, term saturation parameter', 'details': []}, {'value': 0.75, 'description': 'b, length normali
zation parameter', 'details': []}, {'value': 504.0, 'description': 'dl, length of field (approximate)', 'details': []}, {'value': 497.5, 'description': 'avgdl, ave
rage length of field', 'details': []}]}]}]}, {'value': 1.0089812, 'description': 'weight(title:spill in 2) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:', 'details': [{'value':
1.0089812, 'description': 'score(freq=1.0), computed as boost * idf * tf from:', 'details': [{'value': 2.2, 'description': 'boost', 'details': []}, {'value': 1.02
96195, 'description': 'idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:', 'details': [{'value': 2, 'description': 'n, number of documents containing term'
, 'details': []}, {'value': 6, 'description': 'N, total number of documents with field', 'details': []}]}, {'value': 0.44543427, 'description': 'tf, computed as fr
eq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl / avgdl)) from:', 'details': [{'value': 1.0, 'description': 'freq, occurrences of term within document', 'details': []}, {'value'
: 1.2, 'description': 'k1, term saturation parameter', 'details': []}, {'value': 0.75, 'description': 'b, length normalization parameter', 'details': []}, {'value'
: 7.0, 'description': 'dl, length of field', 'details': []}, {'value': 6.6666665, 'description': 'avgdl, average length of field', 'details': []}]}]}]}, {'value':
0.072622515, 'description': 'weight(title:and in 2) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:', 'details': [{'value': 0.072622515, 'description': 'score(freq=1.0), computed
as boost * idf * tf from:', 'details': [{'value': 2.2, 'description': 'boost', 'details': []}, {'value': 0.074107975, 'description': 'idf, computed as log(1 + (N
- n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:', 'details': [{'value': 6, 'description': 'n, number of documents containing term', 'details': []}, {'value': 6, 'description': 'N, t
otal number of documents with field', 'details': []}]}, {'value': 0.44543427, 'description': 'tf, computed as freq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl / avgdl)) from:',
'details': [{'value': 1.0, 'description': 'freq, occurrences of term within document', 'details': []}, {'value': 1.2, 'description': 'k1, term saturation paramete
r', 'details': []}, {'value': 0.75, 'description': 'b, length normalization parameter', 'details': []}, {'value': 7.0, 'description': 'dl, length of field', 'detai
ls': []}, {'value': 6.6666665, 'description': 'avgdl, average length of field', 'details': []}]}]}]}, {'value': 1.0089812, 'description': 'weight(title:overfill in
2) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:', 'details': [{'value': 1.0089812, 'description': 'score(freq=1.0), computed as boost * idf * tf from:', 'details': [{'value':
2.2, 'description': 'boost', 'details': []}, {'value': 1.0296195, 'description': 'idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:', 'details': [{'value'
: 2, 'description': 'n, number of documents containing term', 'details': []}, {'value': 6, 'description': 'N, total number of documents with field', 'details': []}
]}, {'value': 0.44543427, 'description': 'tf, computed as freq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl / avgdl)) from:', 'details': [{'value': 1.0, 'description': 'freq, oc
currences of term within document', 'details': []}, {'value': 1.2, 'description': 'k1, term saturation parameter', 'details': []}, {'value': 0.75, 'description': '
b, length normalization parameter', 'details': []}, {'value': 7.0, 'description': 'dl, length of field', 'details': []}, {'value': 6.6666665, 'description': 'avgdl
, average length of field', 'details': []}]}]}]}, {'value': 1.0089812, 'description': 'weight(title:prevention in 2) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:', 'details':
[{'value': 1.0089812, 'description': 'score(freq=1.0), computed as boost * idf * tf from:', 'details': [{'value': 2.2, 'description': 'boost', 'details': []}, {'va
lue': 1.0296195, 'description': 'idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:', 'details': [{'value': 2, 'description': 'n, number of documents contai
ning term', 'details': []}, {'value': 6, 'description': 'N, total number of documents with field', 'details': []}]}, {'value': 0.44543427, 'description': 'tf, comp
uted as freq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl / avgdl)) from:', 'details': [{'value': 1.0, 'description': 'freq, occurrences of term within document', 'details': []}
, {'value': 1.2, 'description': 'k1, term saturation parameter', 'details': []}, {'value': 0.75, 'description': 'b, length normalization parameter', 'details': []}
, {'value': 7.0, 'description': 'dl, length of field', 'details': []}, {'value': 6.6666665, 'description': 'avgdl, average length of field', 'details': []}]}]}]},
{'value': 0.072622515, 'description': 'weight(title:18 in 2) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:', 'details': [{'value': 0.072622515, 'description': 'score(freq=1.0),
computed as boost * idf * tf from:', 'details': [{'value': 2.2, 'description': 'boost', 'details': []}, {'value': 0.074107975, 'description': 'idf, computed as lo
g(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:', 'details': [{'value': 6, 'description': 'n, number of documents containing term', 'details': []}, {'value': 6, 'descriptio
n': 'N, total number of documents with field', 'details': []}]}, {'value': 0.44543427, 'description': 'tf, computed as freq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl / avgdl)
) from:', 'details': [{'value': 1.0, 'description': 'freq, occurrences of term within document', 'details': []}, {'value': 1.2, 'description': 'k1, term saturation
parameter', 'details': []}, {'value': 0.75, 'description': 'b, length normalization parameter', 'details': []}, {'value': 7.0, 'description': 'dl, length of field
', 'details': []}, {'value': 6.6666665, 'description': 'avgdl, average length of field', 'details': []}]}]}]}, {'value': 0.072622515, 'description': 'weight(title:
aac in 2) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:', 'details': [{'value': 0.072622515, 'description': 'score(freq=1.0), computed as boost * idf * tf from:', 'details': [{
'value': 2.2, 'description': 'boost', 'details': []}, {'value': 0.074107975, 'description': 'idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:', 'details':
[{'value': 6, 'description': 'n, number of documents containing term', 'details': []}, {'value': 6, 'description': 'N, total number of documents with field', 'det
ails': []}]}, {'value': 0.44543427, 'description': 'tf, computed as freq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl / avgdl)) from:', 'details': [{'value': 1.0, 'description':
'freq, occurrences of term within document', 'details': []}, {'value': 1.2, 'description': 'k1, term saturation parameter', 'details': []}, {'value': 0.75, 'descr
iption': 'b, length normalization parameter', 'details': []}, {'value': 7.0, 'description': 'dl, length of field', 'details': []}, {'value': 6.6666665, 'descriptio
n': 'avgdl, average length of field', 'details': []}]}]}]}, {'value': 1.5095675, 'description': 'weight(title:78.045 in 2) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:', 'deta
ils': [{'value': 1.5095675, 'description': 'score(freq=1.0), computed as boost * idf * tf from:', 'details': [{'value': 2.2, 'description': 'boost', 'details': []}
, {'value': 1.5404451, 'description': 'idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:', 'details': [{'value': 1, 'description': 'n, number of documents
containing term', 'details': []}, {'value': 6, 'description': 'N, total number of documents with field', 'details': []}]}, {'value': 0.44543427, 'description': 'tf
, computed as freq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl / avgdl)) from:', 'details': [{'value': 1.0, 'description': 'freq, occurrences of term within document', 'details
': []}, {'value': 1.2, 'description': 'k1, term saturation parameter', 'details': []}, {'value': 0.75, 'description': 'b, length normalization parameter', 'details
': []}, {'value': 7.0, 'description': 'dl, length of field', 'details': []}, {'value': 6.6666665, 'description': 'avgdl, average length of field', 'details': []}]}
]}]}, {'value': 1.0, 'description': 'ConstantScore(title.keyword:Spill and Overfill Prevention 18 AAC 78.045)', 'details': []}]}}
```

With `script_score`

```
{'query': {
    'function_score': {
        'query': {
            'bool': {
                'should': [ 
                    {'match': {'legal_language': 'inspections and testing 691'}},
                    {'match': {'title': 'inspections and testing 691'}}
                ]
            }
        },
        'script_score': {
            'script': {'source': "doc['title'].value"}
        }
    }
}}
```

Mapping

```
{
  "articles" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "abstract" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "categories" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "cfr40_part280" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "citation" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "effective_date" : {
          "type" : "date"
        },
        "id" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "legal_language" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "local_regulation" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "reference_images" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "state" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "tags" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "title" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "unique_id" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Traceback

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "D:\work_projects\dewey_project\webapp\articles\services\elasticsearch_service.py",
> line 103, in retrieve_articles
>     result = current_app.elasticsearch.search(   File "d:\work_projects\dewey_project\venv\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\client\utils.py",
> line 84, in _wrapped
>     return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)   File "d:\work_projects\dewey_project\venv\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\client\__init__.py",
> line 1547, in search
>     return self.transport.perform_request(   File "d:\work_projects\dewey_project\venv\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\transport.py",
> line 351, in perform_request
>     status, headers_response, data = connection.perform_request(   File
> "d:\work_projects\dewey_project\venv\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\connection\http_urllib3.py",
> line 261, in perform_request
>     self._raise_error(response.status, raw_data)   File "d:\work_projects\dewey_project\venv\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\connection\base.py",
> line 181, in _raise_error
>     raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)( elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400,
> 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'runtime error')
```

Comment: Just clarifying few things, are you trying to give more relevance(score) to a document if title is matched?

Comment: @Sharmiko not..

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to achieve, if you want to increment by other value you have to specify `boost` parameter. If that's not what you are trying to do, it would be helpful if you could explain it more specifically.

Comment: @Sharmiko I need to count the score only `"match": {"title": text}`, _not the whole query_ (as default).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite clear what you are trying to achieve, but it looks like you want to receive TF/IDF score for a document based on a match only on the `title` field. And also you want to put additional constraints to your query. If so, you should use the `filter` clauses for the `bool` query. They will not modify your score but will filter the results based on the match in them.

```
{
    "bool": {
        "should": [
            {"match": {"title": "Spill and Overfill Prevention 18 AAC 78.045"}}
        ],
        "filter": [
            {"match": {"abstract": "Spill and Overfill Prevention 18 AAC 78.045"}},
            {"terms": {"state.keyword": ["Alaska", "Alabama"]}
        ]
    }
}
```

This will return a bit different results than your original query because it will require a match of the `abstract` field on query `Spill and Overfill Prevention 18 AAC 78.045`. If you want to keep the behavior of the original query then you should move it as a constant score query inside the `should` block

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {"match": {"title": "Spill and Overfill Prevention 18 AAC 78.045"}},
                {"constant_score": {
                    "filter": {
                        "match": {"legal_language": "Spill and Overfill Prevention 18 AAC 78.045"}
                    }
                }}
            ],
            "filter": [
                {"terms": {"state.keyword": ["Alaska", "Alabama"]]}},
            ],
        }
    }
}
```

and then subtract 1 from the result score.

Comment: I need to save all results. Can you give an example of second way, please?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to take control over scoring process, there is a `function_score` query which lets you customize and replace original query `_score`. You can look at the `function_score` query [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html).

Comment: I have tried this with no success. Could you help me with the query?

Comment: What about this query:

`"function_score": {
      "query": {
        [ put your query here]
      },
      "script_score": {
        "script": {
          "source": "doc['title'].value"
        }
      }
    }`

Comment: `RequestError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'runtime error')`

Comment: I think your query is not formatted correctly. 
Make sure it looks like this one:
`    {
        'query': {
            'function_score': {
                'query': {
                    'bool': {
                        [ rest of your query]
                    }
                },
                'script_score': {
                    'script': {
                        'source': "doc['title'].value"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: I added my query in question

Comment: That's strange. I can run that query without any errors.

Comment: Maybe problem with mapping?

Comment: can you paste whole error? You can hide sensitive information if there is any.

Comment: Updated traceback

Comment: what version of elastic are you running?

Comment: "number" : "7.7.1",

Comment: I don't know why it is complaining. Maybe there is something wrong with your database. Try to search for similar problem.